# display gmail message in google app script gui

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps

What is the best way to display content of gmail message in google apps script web app? 
Here's example of my message raw html:

```
message.getBody();

<div><em><strong><u>TEST</u></strong></em></div>
```

so the question actually is how to show that raw html in some window or pop-up

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean by 'best way'. What are your requirements? How are you currently doing this? Is there a roadblock you've hit?

Comment: the only one requirement  - somehow display message from raw content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is the [HTML Output class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output) which allows you to create basic HTML files in Apps script.

A script such as:

```
function myFunction() {
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
var messages = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
var raw = messages.getPlainBody();
return raw;
}

function doGet() {
   var raw = myFunction();
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b><p>'+ raw + '</p></b>');
 }
```

Will allow you to create a HTML file that has the content of the users last email message whenever they visit the [deployed page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying).

My sample above is very basic, but you can tidy it up to display what you want.