# modal dialog with new spreadsheet api issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm was trying to show html body of gmail message in modal dialog window but faced an error calling  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() method.

[image]

```
...
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(threads[i].getMessages()[0].getBody());
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'My add-on');
...
```

How I can call that dialog? Or may be there is better aproach to display message(some panel or sidebar)?

Answer (score 1):

This prompt box is misleading, as the error must be elsewhere. The new version of Sheets [not only does support the getUI method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets#newer_syntax_for_menus_dialogs_and_sidebars), I believe it's specifically designed for *for* the new version of sheets.

I've [expanded on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831327/display-gmail-message-in-google-app-script-gui) and tested this myself with the following code in the new version of sheets:

```
function getMail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var raw = messages.getPlainBody();
  return raw;
}

function dialogueBox(){ 
  var raw = getMail();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(raw);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'For mk_yo');
}
```

and it displays the prompt with no issues, as shown [here](http://prntscr.com/54sszi). Try creating a new sheet with a new script and run the code above. Additionally, you can try ensuring that the sheet that you're adding this to is definitely using the new version of sheets.

In relation to if there's a better approach by displaying a side panel, yes you can use [custom sidebars in the new version of Google sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)(and only the new version), but as this still uses the 'getUI' method, this won't resolve your current error, as this is not where the issue lies.